# Impact of batch_size in predict method of tf.keras.Model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, predict, batchsize

The `predict` method of a `tf.keras.Model` takes the following arguments:

```
predict(
    x,
    batch_size=None,
    verbose='auto',
    steps=None,
    callbacks=None,
    max_queue_size=10,
    workers=1,
    use_multiprocessing=False
)
```

What is the point of specifying the batch_size? What are the ways in which it impacts the predictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batching only affects the CPU/GPU RAM memory needs and not the predicted values.